# I want print the value from sqlalchemy query of an aggreate function in python-flask

Tags: python, sqlite, flask-sqlalchemy

```
result_1 = Attendance.query.with_entities(Attendance.month, Attendance.year, Attendance.emp_id, func.count(Attendance.status)).filter(and_(Attendance.month == month, Attendance.year == year, Attendance.status == 'Present')).group_by(Attendance.emp_id,Attendance.month,Attendance.year).all()
    #print(len(result_1))
    for r in result_1:
        print(r.month)
        print(r.year)
        print(r.emp_id)
        #print(r.count)
```

Here I can print all the month,year, id values but how can i print the value of count?

Answer (score 0):

Try this .. use `.label()` to give the column a name and then use it later

```
result_1 = Attendance.query.with_entities(Attendance.month, Attendance.year, Attendance.emp_id, func.count(Attendance.status).label('status_count'))
    .filter(and_(Attendance.month == month, Attendance.year == year, Attendance.status == 'Present'))
    .group_by(Attendance.emp_id,Attendance.month,Attendance.year).all()
for r in result_1:
    print(r.month)
    print(r.year)
    print(r.emp_id)
    print(r.status_count)
```